# how do you use public licenses?

Tags: licensing

If i want to use a public license, is it as easy as copying the license and putting it in my source code/making a new file, or is there something special i need to do to use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's a guide](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html) on how to use GNU licenses in your project. From the guide:

> The process involves adding two
>   elements to each source file of your
>   program: a copyright notice (such as
>   “Copyright 1999 Terry Jones”), and a
>   statement of copying permission,
>   saying that the program is distributed
>   under the terms of the GNU General
>   Public License (or the Lesser GPL).

Other public licenses should be similar, but be sure to check the website of the license you're using for specifics.

Comment: Why is it necessary to include copyright notice and a license reference in *each* source file? Why isn't it sufficient just to include LICENSE file with license and copyrights in the distribution/repository?

Comment: @Roman - I think the theory is that the license explains the terms, but the copyright notice and license reference actually bind the source docs to the license.

Answer (score -1):

Just need to include the license and comply with it.

Comment: -1. <rant>This is the perfect example of why you should ask legal questions on a legal forum and programming questions on a programming forum. Why is it that programmers think that asking programmers for legal advice is a good idea? Do they also ask their lawyers for algorithm advice? And why is that programmers think that *giving* legal advice is a good idea?</rant> Now that I got that out of my system: *of course*, the OP *does not* need to comply with the license. He wrote the code. He is the copyright holder. He can do whatever the heck he wants with it.

Comment: Some licenses do have requirements laid out for the content creator as well; some licenses are even copyrighted works, meaning that reproduction carries certain responsibilities. I think that the OP just wants to hear from people who have been in his shoes before.